# jsp update request happens to be invoked by a link

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<tr class="bg-row1">
    <td class="td-highlighted-2">
     <div align="left"><a href="<%=contextPath%>/jsp/admin/UpdateProject.jsp"><%=searchList1.getProjid()%></a></div>
    </td>
    <td class="td-highlighted-2">
      <div align="left"><%=searchList1.getProjname()%></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

here jsp update request happens to be invoked by a link
in updateproject.jsp how can i refer projid and projname value in a text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of scenario `POST` is better suited,

Even if you want to stuck with `GET` , you can use javascript and use [`window.open()`](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) function for your purpose , and build URL dynamically reading fields

Comment: can u please help me with a bit of code since i am a starter in jsp and servlet i am not getting idea how to go about

Comment: have you checked the links provided ?

Comment: you are always welcome (also to upvote & mark it as answer if it is for you )   :)